# Is there a way to optimize a sort in mongodb with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to query a mongodb Database.

I have this :

```
 var filter = BsonDocument.Parse("{$expr: {$ne:['$crc_n', '$crc_n_1']},crc_n_1_exception:{$eq:''}}")
     var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Ascending("update_date");
     int slimit = 400;
    
    List<BsonDocument> docs =  collection.Find(filter, options)
                        .Sort(sort)
                        .Limit(slimit)
                        .ToList();
```

But it takes more than 5 minutes. When i delete these line :

```
.Sort(sort)
```

It takes less than 2 seconds.

So i created an index on update_date

And I tried this :

```
 var options = new FindOptions
                {
                    AllowDiskUse = true,
                    Modifiers = new BsonDocument("$hint", "update_date")
                };
```

But same results : more than 5 minutes.

Is there a way to optimize these query ?

Is creating an index is a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [explain](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/explain/index.html#explain) with the "allPlansExecution" option to see how the query is being performed.

The server might be having trouble with the `field1 != field2` in the expression.  If it is able to use an index for that part of the query, try creating a new compound index that includes the same fields plus the sort field.

If the query executor does not use an index to select documents, it cannot use one to sort.

For more info, take a look at: [Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2020/05/16/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes-the-equality-sort-range-esr-rule/)